# Interpretation of intercept in Helmert coding

Tags: anova, linear-model, contrasts

I have a general, presumably simple, question, but I couldn't find a conclusive answer so far.

Assume I have a simple case of a General Linear Model with one categorical predictor variable, that has 3 levels. This corresponds to a one-way ANOVA with 3 groups.

The Linear Model would then be: $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2$

I use the following standard Helmert contrast codes (I, II) for the three groups A, B, C:

```
     A    B    C
I   -2    1    1
II   0   -1    1
```

Based on these contrast codes, **will the intercept of the linear model represent the mean of all group means? More generally, does this always apply to Helmert contrast coded variables,** regardless of the number of predictor variables or variable levels?

Obviously, the intercept represents the predicted value, when all predictor variables (in this case $X_1$ and $X_2$) equal zero, but I can't figure out if that represents the mean of the group means.

Comment: Does that help: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm?

Comment: I've come across this site before, but unfortunately it doesn't say whether the intercept in Helmert coding equals the mean of all group means.

Comment: Yes it is the case. If you write down regression equations based on the contrast matrix returned by R and try to identify each regression coefficient, you will find that $\beta_0$ is the mean of all levels (like in deviation or sum contrast) while $\beta_i,\, i=1\dots j$, represent sequential comparisons between adjacent categories (2 vs. 1, 3 vs. {1,2}, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! Does that also hold, when I have more than 1 categorical variable and consequently my model contains interaction terms?

Comment: @chl, why not make that an official answer & show how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can easily verify this by carrying out the following steps:

First, express the means of $A$, $B$, and $C$, in terms of the model with the specified contrast:
\begin{eqnarray*}
1\hat{\beta}_{0}-2\hat{\beta}_{1}+0\hat{\beta}_{2} & = & \hat{\mu}_{A}=E(Y_{A})\\
1\hat{\beta}_{0}+1\hat{\beta}_{1}-1\hat{\beta}_{2} & = & \hat{\mu}_{B}=E(Y_{B})\\
1\hat{\beta}_{0}+1\hat{\beta}_{1}+1\hat{\beta}_{2} & = & \hat{\mu}_{C}=E(Y_{C})
\end{eqnarray*}

Here, each $\hat{\mu}_i$ represents the group mean of group $i$, $i=A, B, C$.
Next, place each beta coefficient into a matrix augmented with the
means on the right, and place the matrix in row-reduced echelon form
using Guass-Jordan elimination:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}\\
1 & 1 & -1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{B}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{C}
\end{bmatrix} & \sim & \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 3 & -1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 3 & 1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & \sim & \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 3 & -1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 0 & 2 & | & \left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & \sim & \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 3 & -1 & | & \hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & \sim & \begin{bmatrix}1 & -2 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & \frac{1}{3}\left\{ \left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]\right\} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & \sim & \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & | & \hat{\mu}_{A}+\frac{2}{3}\left\{ \left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]\right\} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & | & \frac{1}{3}\left\{ \left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]\right\} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & | & \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

So, now, we know that the first pivot position corresponds to:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{\beta}{}_{0} & = & \hat{\mu}_{A}+\frac{2}{3}\left\{ \left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\hat{\mu}_{C}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)-\left(\hat{\mu}_{B}-\hat{\mu}_{A}\right)\right]\right\} \\
 & = & \hat{\mu}_{A}-\frac{2}{3}\hat{\mu}_{A}-\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{A}+\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{A}+\frac{2}{3}\hat{\mu}_{B}-\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{B}+\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{C}\\
 & = & \frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{A}+\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{B}+\frac{1}{3}\hat{\mu}_{C}\\
 & = & \frac{\hat{\mu}_{A}+\hat{\mu}_{B}+\hat{\mu}_{C}}{3}
\end{eqnarray*}

The final expression indicates that $\hat{\beta}{}_{0}$, the intercept,
represents the simple mean of the group means.